# JavaScript : display Google ad conditionally

Tags: javascript, adsense

I want to display google ads at vbulletin forum when the thread not contains any crack or serial so I write this code:

```
<div id ="d_content"> post goes here...</div>
<div id="adv_content"></div>
<script>
function isBlank(str) {
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
var str = document.getElementById("d_content").innerHTML;
var pattern = /crack|nulled|serial|register|key|pach|patch/gi;
var Len= str.match(pattern); 
if( isBlank(Len) ) document.write("adv..");
</script>
```

but how to put the google ad code instead of "adv.."
this is my try :

```
    <div id ="d_content"> post goes here...</div>
<div id="adv_content"></div>
<script>
function isBlank(str) {
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
var str = document.getElementById("d_content").innerHTML;
var pattern = /crack|nulled|serial|register|key|pach|patch/gi;
var Len= str.match(pattern); 
if( isBlank(Len) ) document.write("
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1564912551365218";
    /* 728x90, تم إنشاؤها 02/06/11 زهير طه */
    google_ad_slot = "7785253845";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
");
</script>
```

but not worked..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not going to work because browsers will interpret the first `</script>` as the end of your script, eve though it is within a text string.

A workaround is to use an escape/unescape sequence:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript'%3E[your script here]%3C/script%3E"));
```

where `<` is escaped as `%3C` and `>` is escaped as `%3E`.

Comment: thank you thats good but not worked for full ad code, how to write the full code?
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript'%3E[<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1564912551365218";
    /* 728x90, تم إنشاؤها 02/06/11 زهير طه */
    google_ad_slot = "7785253845";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>]%3C/script%3E"));

Comment: You need to **replace** < with %3C and > with %3E, not keep both!